# Cannot find a way to check if a user already exist

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm using the following code to check if a user already exists in a MySQL database, but every time I try to create a new account with an username that has been already chosen, it lets me create it instead of returning an error message.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['B1'])){
    $user=$_POST['U']; 
    $email=$_POST['email']; 
    $pass=$_POST['P'];
    $cpass=$_POST['CP'];

    if($user!=null && $pass!=null && $cpass!=null && $email!=null){
         if($pass==$cpass){
             $sql="SELECT FROM users (username, email, password) WHERE username='$user'";
             $checkuser=mysql_query($sql); 
             if(mysql_num_rows($checkuser)>0){
                  echo"This username has been already taken.";
             }else{
                 $query="INSERT INTO users(username, email, password) VALUES('$user','$email',md5('$pass'))";
             $result=mysql_query($query) or die("error3");
             mysql_close();
             echo "<center><h2>Thanks for have joined us, ".$user."!</h2><br></center>";
             echo"<center><h2>You are now ready to use your account.</h2><br></center>";
             echo"<center><a href='login.php' class='button specialp'>Let's get started</a></center>";  
             }
        }
    }else{
        echo"<center><p><h2>Oops, something went wrong!<h2></p></center>";
        echo"<center><a href='signup.php' class='button specialp'>Try again</a></center>";
    }

}

?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your username column in your DB (and stuff like email) should definitely be unique. When you did this, you can't add the username anymore and the insert query will fail. You then can simply check for the correct insert execution

Comment: I dont know if you are using something legacy but I would advise using the http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers PHP PDO extension or using the http://codular.com/php-mysqli Mysqli extension if you can

Comment: Thank you all! I followed michael's suggestion and it works great! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In your code section,

```
$sql="SELECT username, email, password FROM users  WHERE username='$user'";
$checkuser=mysql_query($sql); 
if(mysql_num_rows() > 0) {
......
```

try to replace that part above of code and see